# Crypt_Blowfish backward compatibility from pear to phpseclib

Tags: php, pear, phpseclib, blowfish, crypt

I want to migrate my system from `pear/Crypt/Blowfish` to `phpseclib/Crypt/Blowfish` lib.

I need to have a total backward compatibility. So, What are differences between these two libraries ?

I found [in this link](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/125) that "PEAR's Crypt_Blowfish uses ECB by default, and phpseclib's uses CBC".

So I configured phpseclib to work with ECB, but is still a difference between two libs. Which one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution :

By default, pear crypt package uses `chr(0)` to padding strings wich doesn't have a length multiple of 8 (block size). But phpseclib uses integers instead.

Here is the solution :

```
$crypt = new Crypt_Blowfish(CRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$crypt->setKey('mysecretkey');
$crypt->disablePadding();
// You must padding your input here with chr(0),
// to put your input length to a multiple of 8
$block_size = 8;
$pad = $block_size - (strlen($text) % $block_size);
$text = str_pad($text, strlen($text) + $pad, chr(0));
$encrypted = $crypt->encrypt($text);
```